# Concatinating mp4 files to a single mp4 file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation, mp4

I have some mp4 video files with me and i need to concatenate them one by one and make a single MP4 video file.

I came to know about FFMPEG through which we can concat files.

I tried doing

```sh
ffmpeg -i concat:'file1.mp4|file2.mp4' -vcodec copy -acodec copy  -y OutCome.mp4
```

But while executing the command i always get file2.mp4,no such file exists,but the file is there in the folder.

What i am doing wrong? or is there any other tool which can help me achieve this target through command line.

Comment: Try to use spaces around the "|" like this " | ".

Answer (score 0):

You can only `concat` files which "like" being `concat`ed

```sh
ffmpeg -i q.mp4 -c copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb q.ts
ffmpeg -i r.mp4 -c copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb r.ts
ffmpeg -i "concat:q.ts|r.ts" -c copy -bsf aac_adtstoasc qr.mp4
```

[Joining H264 *without* re-encoding](https://superuser.com/q/133413/joining-h264-w)

Another option is the `concat` demuxer

[How to concatenate (join, merge) media files](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files)

Comment: Thanks for the reply,i tried creating ts file from my mp4 but it not showing any video

Comment: i have tried this too but its not happening

Comment: Penny  i have two ts files and i tried to concatenate them using ffpmeg.i am getting the combined file but i cant see the video in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using MP4Joiner. I have used this tool to accomplish exactly what you appear to be attempting.

*PS* sorry about the reply to the old question, but for others browsing here this tool works very well.