# ffmpeg - trim and merge video clips without reencoding

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have two videos that I want to trim, and then merge the trimmed output. They're all the same size/codec so I'd like to do that without re-encoding too much. But if I do:

```
ffmpeg -i clip1.mp4 -ss 1.2 -t 2.0 -c copy clip1.trimmed.mp4
ffmpeg -i clip2.mp4 -ss 0.2 -t 2.0 -c copy clip2.trimmed.mp4
ffmpeg -filter_complex '[0:0] [0:1] [1:0] [1:1] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]'\
-map [v] -map [a] -c:v libx264 merge.mp4
```

The merged video has issues with audio/video synchronization. This doesn't happen if I replace `-c copy` by `-vcodec libx264` in the trimming command. Is it possible that by not re-encoding, something goes wrong with the timing?

---

The correct answer, from Mulvya:

```
ffmpeg -ss 1.2 -t 2.0 -i clip1.mp4 -ss 0.2 -t 2.0 -i clip2.mp4 \
   -filter_complex '[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" \
   -map [v] -map [a] -c:v libx264 merge.mp4
```

In case that helps, I would add that the syntaxe to add clip specific filters is like:

```
ffmpeg -ss 1.2 -t 2.0 -i clip1.mp4 -ss 0.2 -t 2.0 -i clip2.mp4 \
   -filter_complex '[0:v]scale=1920:960[v0]; [v0] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" \
   -map [v] -map [a] -c:v libx264 merge.mp4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are ultimately re-encoding the merged segments, just do it in one command,

```
ffmpeg -ss 1.2 -t 2.0 -i clip1.mp4 -ss 0.2 -t 2.0 -i clip2.mp4 \
       -filter_complex '[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" \
       -map [v] -map [a] -c:v libx264 merge.mp4
```

Answer (score 3):

Merging videos without re-encoding is possible and described in the answers to [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/133413/joining-h264-without-re-encoding).

Splitting a video without re-encoding may only be possible for lossless formats. Lossy codecs like h264 (usually) use a series of keyframes and then encode intermediate frames as diffs between current frame and the previous frame. (This is why you get that weird drifting in a damaged video why is goes away on a scene change.)

Theoretically, you might be able to split a video if the cut is just before a key frame. Figuring out where those keyframes are and how to make the cut there is beyond me.

Comment: Ok thanks! Since the user choses exactly where to cut, I'll have to re-encode the trimmed bit

Comment: To figure that out, you can look at the NAL packet headers. Key frames have a very specific header.